# Create file usb storage android?

Tags: android

Unable to create a folder or file in USB storage android version above 5.0+ non-root device using this method.
 File root = new File("/mnt/media_rw/usbotg-sda1", "Notes");
File gpxfile = new File(root, "Sample.txt");   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile); writer.append("ANDROID");  writer.flush();  writer.close();

Exception : /mnt/media_rw/usbotg-sda1/Notes/Sample.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Declare write permission in your manifest and also request for runtime permission. After that write to your application's scoped directory using `context.getExternalStorageDir(..)`

Comment: i also added write external storage permission in manifest.xml file.

Comment: you need to ask for runtime permissions as well

Comment: I think runtime permission is needed for Android lollipop(5.0)  .  permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation

Comment: Anyone give storage access framework example in android 5.0 ?